# SVN log details of uncommitted merge

Tags: svn, merge, commit, mergeinfo

I had recently merged my branch with the latest revision of the trunk. However, I did not commit at that time and do not remember with which trunk version I had merged. Currently, I need the trunk revision information during the merge. Is it possible to access the revision number of the trunk at the time of svn merge?

Comment: Have a look at the [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) on the root of your checkout. If you're using TortoiseSVN it would be relatively easy to look at the diff of the mergeinfo

Answer (score 0):

You **don't need** to know latest-merged revision from trunk for subsequent merges from trunk - SVN will use mergeinfo anyway and does not re-merge the same revisions again

But @sameer-singh is right anyway